# How do I compute the torque in ft lbs to turn a screw and move a 2000 lb weight?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mathematics

I am having trouble locating the calculations for finding the torque, in ft/lbs, required to turn a 1/2" screw with 13 threads per inch and pull 2000lbs 6 inches.
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circumstance of your screw is d*r = 0.5*3.141= 1.57 inch. So the slope of the thread is (1/13 )/1.57= 0.048 since this is a small slope we can assume sin  of the slope angle = angle

If we ignore the friction which can be substantial, we need 2000* 0.048= 98lbs tangential force.

So your torque is

T= f*r

T = 98 *0.5/2= 24 lbs. inch